# How to restrict facebook to not pick image from my webpage?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have applied facebook share code to share things on facebook, from that page where users share things on facebook, I mentioned `og:image` tag which facebook understands to get image from the web page. If I am removing this tag then facebook automatically picks any image from the web page, and if I pass a blank value in that tag even then facebook picks any image from the web page.

I don't want any image in any post that users share on facebook. Can anyone please help me that what can I do to not let facebook pick any image from the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the .htaccess file which configures some aspects of an apache server like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?escale-japon.com(/)?.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|doc|wav|bmp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp3|zip|rar)$ http://www.escale-japon.com/graphisme/vol.jpe [R,NC]
```

This will forbid to pick images by their url automaticaly, but users can download them.

Comment: ¿Would you mind explaining what the "escale-japon" part does?

Comment: Sure, it's just the url for the website. You have to change it by yours.

Comment: So, actually that would block ANY hotlinking to any media on your site, not just by Facebook.

Comment: yes, it changes the url of the specified medias, so an external website can't access to them. You can allow some websites to access at these medias by putting some RewriteCond rules